# After adding "arm64-v8a" in my ndk this following error pops up java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libNBioBSP.so"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android. in android 14

Specific Device: Galaxy Tab A7 Lite

My application shows the below warning after installing it on a Galaxy Tab A7 Lite for the first time, only in Android 14:

This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android.
check for an update or contact the app's developer.

After adding a blow line with "arm64-v8a" in my gradle the issue is resolved

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi","arm64-v8a"
}
```

However now I got this error

java. lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libNBioBSP.so"

This issue pops up. how do fix this issue?

Comment: Check the dependencies (direct and indirect). One of the libraries seem to require the mentioned libraries but misses the arm64-v8a version of that library. Identify the dependency and check if there is an updated version of the library.